# how do I carry on my python script after I execute a ssh

Tags: python, paramiko

At the moment I'm running my python program through my linux terminal.

In one part of an elif conditional statement it executes a linux ssh command to remote into another machine `os.system('ssh ' + <varWithHostName>`.

After it SSH's into another Machine it seems to exit my program. How do I continue the execution of the next part of my program after it has ssh'ed into another machine.

Paramiko module I hear could be the answer? or can this be done without the module?

Comment: Show your whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to execute the script on the remote machine with ssh you could run the script using ssh. e.g.

```sh
os.system('ssh ' + <varWithHostName> + ' foo.py')
```

given that `foo.py` exists on the machine

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/

Comment: Oh cool, for some reason it appends <foo.py> to the end of the varWithHostName, resulting in a incorrect hostname. Error output = ssh: Could not resolve hostname rorodostuff.py: No address associated with hostname. roro = <varWithHostName> dostuff.py = <foo.py>

Comment: You might need to check if 'foo.py' exists in the directory on that machine; I'm actually not sure what went wrong there, but if you have the ssh command inside `foo.py` I'm not sure if you can run the rest of `foo.py` in the `elif` statement, you might have to run whatever is in the `elif` statement from the remote machine